# Wordpress Installation on Web Server with different port not working

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess

I activated the Apache server and installed MySQL on a Mac OS X Lion server at my place of work yesterday. I am running it on an alternate port, port 81. If I, for instance, point the browser to

```
http://192.168.0.1:81/phpMyAdmin/
```

phpMyAdmin opens up and I can make adjustments to my database.

If I however import a Wordpress database and install Wordpress in

```
http://192.168.0.1:81/myNewSite
```

then I get a 404 Not Found and the address bar shows

```
http://192.168.0.1/myNewSite/
```

This is with the standard Wordpress .htaccess file in the root of /myNewSite.

Wordpress seems to be making a database connection too, seeing as I had my socket wrong in the beginning and got the message "Error Establishing a Database Connection." When I corrected the socket it started redirecting me as mentioned above.

In my Wordpress Databse the siteurl row/field is set to

```
http://192.168.0.1:81/myNewSite/
```

Could someone let me know if I should add a Rewrite Rule to my htaccess file or is there some other setting I should be looking at.

I am not fluent with .htaccess syntax, so if the problem is there I would very much appreciate if there could be a clear indication of where any new code should be inserted and if any other lines of code should be adjusted.

Thank you

Comment: This is a new wordpress install?

Comment: Nope. I have migrated the exact Wordpress site to another server actually and it worked fine. All that seems to have changed is the port number

Comment: You need to adjust the configuration of wordpress so that the site url is added with the port number.

Comment: Have a look here http://wordpress.org/support/topic/wordpress-wont-load-after-changing-ports - the 5th answer..

Comment: Hi Matthew, see I don't have access to my Wordpress installation at all, but in the past if I've gone and edited the siteurl in the database it worked fine.

Comment: http://sketchpad.co.za/screencapture.jpg. Could you have a look at this screencapture and let me know if it looks right?

Comment: Got it sorted, thanks guys.